# Moving files >5 gig to AWS S3 using a Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

We are experiencing problems with files produced by Java code which are written locally and then copied by the Data Pipeline to S3. The error mentions file size.

I would have thought that if multipart uploads is required, then the Pipeline would figure that out. I wonder if there is a way of configuring the Pipeline so that it indeed uses multipart uploading. Because otherwise the current Java code which is agnostic about S3 has to write directly to S3 or has to do what it used to and then use multipart uploading -- in fact, I would think the code would just directly write to S3 and not worry about uploading.

Can anyone tell me if Pipelines can use multipart uploading and if not, can you suggest whether the correct approach is to have the program write directly to S3 or to continue to write to local storage and then perhaps have a separate program be invoked within the same Pipeline which will do the multipart uploading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, based on AWS support, is that indeed 5 gig files can't be uploaded directly to S3. And there is no way currently for a Data Pipeline to say, "You are trying to upload a large file, so I will do something special to handle this." It simply fails.

This may change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Data Pipeline CopyActivity does not support files larger than 4GB.  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-copyactivity.html

This is below the 5GB limit imposed by S3 for each file-part put.

You need to write your own script wrapping AWS CLI or S3cmd (older).  This script may be executed as a shell activity.

Writing directly to S3 may be an issue as S3 does not support append operations - unless you can somehow write multiple smaller objects in a folder.